# Post Warning In Mobile Version Doesn't Show

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

I was on my smartphone today(win7) browsing SO trying to kill some time. One of the things I noticed was when I posted a reply to a comment, it wouldn't post. I kept trying and trying and couldn't figure out why. Then I remembered the minimal character limit(I don't remember how many off-hand), so I typed in a sentence and it posted.

So to a new user who doesn't know about the character limit(or forgets it for that matter), and doesn't get a visual warning as to why the post wasn't accepted, so right would right off the bat assume SO doesn't work on their mobile device.

Perhaps the powers that be can find a solution to this.

I'm not saying this is a bug or top priority situation, but some point it wouldn't hurt to address it. Maybe just a single sentence line saying minimal # characters just above or below the textarea when posting on mobile.